# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'BulkyBookWeb.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel', but this ViewDataDictionary

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, .net-6.0

using razorPages Identity in .NET6

while registering a user before rendering the register page it is getting an exception

**InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'BulkyBookWeb.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.String'.**

**Here is the code behind and  Register.cshtml**

```js
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace BulkyBookWeb.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<IdentityUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private IdentityUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<IdentityUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        private IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>)_userStore;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to register.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Rafi, The error message show that The Model type mismatch , it need's the `string` but you pass the `RegisterModel` , You need to debug where the Model type mismatch

Comment: Am using Identity in MVC application with. Net 6. Not edited scaffolded code.For same configuration Identity previous versions are working but not new one